# Rspec controller test is passing nil instead of the @user object I'm sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

employer_profiles_controller_spec.rb

```
 it 'assigns the profile as @profile' do
  profile = FactoryGirl.create(:employer_profile, :user_id => @user)
  get :show, :user_id => @user 
  assigns(:employer_profile).should eq(profile)
end
```

route.rb

```
get '/employer_profiles/:user_id', to: 'employer_profiles#show'
```

I'm logging in `@user` in the the spec with a devise macro `login_user` located at

```
module ControllerMacros
 def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

and finally the error

```
Failure/Error: get :show, :user_id => @user
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:user_id=>nil, :controller=>"employer_profiles", :action=>"show"}
 # ./spec/controllers/employer_profiles_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in     <top (required)>'
```

Comment: should user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) be @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) in the before(:each)?

Comment: I get an undefined var `user` inside the `FactoryGirl.create(:employer_profile, :user_id => :user)` so apparently @user is defined for the first create()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have defined `@user` in nowhere. So, define it in helper

```
def login_user
  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end
end
```

Then the argument of param for `get` should be within a hash.

Instead of

```
get :show, :user_id => @user
```

You need

```
get :show, {:user_id => @user.id}
```

Comment: I had to change `profile = FactoryGirl.create(:employer_profile, :user_id => @user)` to `profile = FactoryGirl.create(:employer_profile, :user => @user)` as well, but you're fix was necessary too, thanks!